# Accesing to my carrierwave model object with an attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, carrierwave

I'm trying to put a file link with a partial render, something like this:

```
#Main haml file
= render :partial => 'file_upload', :locals => {:f => f, :file_download => 'residence_cert'}
#Inside the partial
%a{:href => @postulant_info[file_download]}
```

But this is making a link just with the file name, not the full path to the file. Then realized that `@postulant_info[file_download]` is just giving me a String with the file name, not the carrierwave object

```
-logger.debug @postulant_info.residence_cert #this is returning my carrierwave object -> 'DocumentUploader'
-logger.debug @postulant_info['residence_cert'] #but this one is just returning a String, the DB record with the file name
```

One solution could be put the url in the render as a local like `= render :partial => 'file_upload', :locals => {:f => f, :file_download => 'residence_cert', :url => @postulant_info.residence_cert.url}` but I think "should" be unnecessary when you have the  attribute name inside the partial template.
Any thought would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I could achieve it with:

```
%a{:href => @postulant_info.send(file_download)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm extremely uncertain about what your problem exactly is, and what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to output a link to a file, in your partial then

```
%a{:href => @postulant_info.residence_cert.url}
```

is enough. `@postulant_info.residence_cert` will give you an instance of the uploader (`DocumentUploader`), and the `#url` method returns the complete url of the uploaded file

By the way, you should avoid using instance var in your partials, the only variables a partial should use are the it's been given.

Comment: But my problem is that the template I'm gonna use it with another attributes besides `residence_cert`. I need a generic way to do it